# Error in installing ns2.35 on ubuntu

Tags: ram, ns2

I'm getting the following error while trying to install ns2.35:

```
Error in `ns': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000c7c850
Aborted
```

Are there any methods to bypass this error?

Comment: Please edit your question to include Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0):

'ns2.35' Howto : `sudo apt-get install g++ g++-4.9 autoconf libtool libxmu-dev xgraph`

`tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz`
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

```
cd ns-allinone-2.35/
export CC=gcc-4.9 CXX=g++-4.9 && ./install
cd ns-2.35/
sudo make install      ( 'make install' will copy 'ns' to /usr/local/bin/ )
cp ns ns-orig          ( this is your backup if you do changes to ns-2.35 )
sudo cp ns-orig /usr/local/bin/
cd ../nam-1.15/
sudo make install
```

That's it. No more to do. Simulation : `$ ns file.tcl` or `$ ns-orig file.tcl`